# Swift 3 and Firebase - Cannot add annotations with firebase array, prints to console though

Tags: swift, firebase, annotations, firebase-realtime-database, mapkitannotation

In my console, I can access Firebase latitude, longitude, and name of restaurant.  I have a few print statements that I use to test that I am getting the values I needed.  When I try to assign these values into an `annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(with the respective info here)` I still can't get this function to print in maps.

I mainly created a function so that I can call it in `viewDidLoad()` so that everything I want automatically comes up when this page of the app loads.

I also created an action for a button so that when a user clicks a button on shown on the view controller, it also prints the location but THAT case also is not working.  When I make coordinates I also do not know if I need ! on `res.latitude` and `res.longitude!`…. When I take it off it still does not work.  A previous project I created I added annotations the same way I did here MINUS the firebase array.  I created one myself with struct variables (`title`, `latitude`, `longitude`) in them that are later called.

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseStorage
import FirebaseDatabase
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class MapViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {//add last 2 delegates/protocols.conforming

   //firebase refrences
   var dataBaseRef: FIRDatabaseReference! {
   return FIRDatabase.database().reference()
}

var storageRef: FIRStorageReference! {
    return FIRStorage.storage().reference()
}
var restaurantArray = [Restaurant]()


@IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!
@IBOutlet weak var segments: UISegmentedControl!

let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    title = "Maps"
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Main Menu", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(SSASideMenu.presentLeftMenuViewController))


    self.locationManager.delegate = self//as soon as loaded find location--conforms to delegate
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest//best location
    self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()//only want location when using app
    self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()//turn on location manager..make location start looking
    self.mapView.showsUserLocation = true//shows blue dot

    displayRestaurants()
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)
    fetchRestaurants()
    displayRestaurants()
}
//see if you want to give it a try!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
func fetchRestaurants(){
    FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("AthensRestaurants/Restaurants").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        var results = [Restaurant]()

        for res in snapshot.children{
            let res = Restaurant(snapshot: res as! FIRDataSnapshot)
            results.append(res)
        }
        self.restaurantArray = results
    }) { (error) in
        print("error encountered dumbass")
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
  //work here!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
func displayRestaurants(){

    //array already created--using a firebase array


    for res in restaurantArray {
        let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        annotation.title = res.name
        print(res.name)
        let x = res.latitude //shows that this works and I can retrieve data!!!
        print (x! as Double)
        let y = res.longitude
        print(y! as Double)
        annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: res.latitude!, longitude: res.longitude!) //Should the exclamation marks be there "!"
        mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
    }
}


//A way of testing
@IBAction func test12(sender: UIButton) {
    displayRestaurants() //another way i tried makiing anotations show....!!!!!!!!!
}


//below works on seperate projects
//MARK: - Location Delegate Methods
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {//didupdate is contiously called so below is continuously called
    let location = locations[0]
    let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.01, 0.01)

    let myLocation:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(location.coordinate.latitude, location.coordinate.longitude)
    let region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(myLocation, span)//lat long--region that we want map to scope to--parameters is closeness zoom
    self.mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)//since we have thise we can stop updating eventually
    self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()

}

//check for errors
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {//should be NSError but
    print("Errors:" + error.localizedDescription)
    //displayRestaurants()
}
//segment changer for terrain, hybrid, and regular---just allows different types of map views
@IBAction func segChange(_ sender: Any) {
    switch segments.selectedSegmentIndex {
    case 0:
        mapView.mapType = MKMapType.standard
        break
    case 1:
        mapView.mapType = MKMapType.satellite
        break
    case 2:
        mapView.mapType = MKMapType.hybridFlyover
        break
    default:
        break
    }
}   
}
```

Comment: If you print the restaurantArray in func displayRestaurants(){, what do you you get? seems to me that you calling the displayRestaurants function before the fetchRestaurants() has filled the restaurantArray. Also why call the displayRestaurants() twice (in viewWillAppear AND viewDidLoad?)

Comment: In my fetch method I can get ALL the data from restaurants which is more than just latitude and longitude but all methods start with the restaurant array at 0 or nil. So there are no values in the restaurant array until it gets appended. I'm trying to figure out how I can put the fetch method within the display method and print annotations right there in that method while it's being appended. (since I know that fetch is working). But for now, display prints [] while fetch prints [ with every restaurant info] since it's appending

Comment: Can't you just put "let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
...
        mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)" right after the  "let res = Restaurant(snapshot: res as! FIRDataSnapshot)", instead of the function? and take out both displayRestaurants()?

Comment: What about extracting the latitude and longitude from that array? Because right now I have an array of objects and each object has different variables such as name, cuisine type, phone number, latitude, longitude and etc.

Comment: I did what you said since it seemed about right.  Luckily, the restaurant name, latitude and longitude ARE printing in the console like i coded it to do, it just does not want to add the annotations when open the map on the app.  Just shows current location.

Comment: try:
let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: res.latitude!, longitude: res.longitude!)
annotation.title = res.name 
                    
 DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in
 self.mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
})

Comment: I got a blank map.  Ex. It showed North America with no annotations points.